# Ignore PMD rule for methods with a Test annotation

Tags: java, junit, abstract-syntax-tree, pmd

I use PMD for a Spring Boot project which contains [`MockMvc`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html) tests. The class enforces the user to catch the general `Exception`.

```
class MockMvc {
    public ResultActions perform(RequestBuilder requestBuilder) throws Exception {}
}
```

The usage leads to a PMD error - [SignatureDeclareThrowsException](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.6.1/pmd-java/rules/java/strictexception.html#SignatureDeclareThrowsException). I would like to suppress the check for all `@Test` methods. Therefore I tried to follow a [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28739273/846163) but the configuration change has no effect.

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/strictexception.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException" >
    <properties>
        <!-- Ignore @Test methods -->
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="
        //ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/Annotation/MarkerAnnotation//Name[@Image='Test']" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

How could I achieve it?

---

*Abstract Syntax Tree* shows the following sub tree for the test method.

```
> ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration
  > Annotation
    > MarkerAnnotation
      > Name:Test
  > MethodDeclaration:(public)
    > ResultType:(void)
    ...
```

Comment: Maybe you could try this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815987 possible duplicate. Although it will exclude the whole class most likely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem with test methods can be solved in version with the `IgnoreJUnitCompletely` property.

```
<!-- PMD > version 6.* -->
<rule ref="category/java/design.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException" >
    <properties>
        <property name="IgnoreJUnitCompletely" value="true" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Before PMD 6 you have to take the rule from `typeresolution.xml` but not `strictexception.xml`.

```
<!-- PMD > version 4.* -->
<rule ref="rulesets/java/typeresolution.xml/SignatureDeclareThrowsException">
    <properties>
        <property name="IgnoreJUnitCompletely" value="true" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

But it doesn't answer the question about the `violationSuppressXPath` problem.

Comment: Cool finding, upvoted. But this feature is there since 4.0, should work in 5.7.0 https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.7.0/xref/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/typeresolution/rules/SignatureDeclareThrowsException.html unless it needs one of the recent 6.2.0 fixes.

Comment: @hakamairi Thanks. There are 2 `SignatureDeclareThrowsException` rules, packages `strictexception` and `typeresolution`. Your suggestion works for the second package only.  What a mess. ;-) I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PMD documentation](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.5.0/pmd_rules_java_bestpractices.html#junit4suitesshouldusesuiteannotation), the JUnit4TestShouldUseTestAnnotation part

```
//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[
   matches(@Image, $testClassPattern)
    or ExtendsList/ClassOrInterfaceType[pmd-java:typeIs('junit.framework.TestCase')]]

/ClassOrInterfaceBody/ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration[MethodDeclaration[@Public=true()]/MethodDeclarator[starts-with(@Image, 'test')]]
[not(Annotation//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.junit.Test')])]
```

Suggest that `Annotation//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.junit.Test')]` should be enough

Comment: Doesn't work, `<property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="Annotation//Name[pmd-java:typeIs('org.junit.Test')]" />`

Comment: Sorry mate, I have to setup properly to test this locally. Would you be so kind to publish a boiler plate for this one on github or similar?

Comment: You could use the spring example, complete folder - https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-testing-web.

Comment: `//MethodDeclaration/../Annotation/MarkerAnnotation/Name[@Image='Test']` worked for me.

Comment: Happy that you found the answer you were looking for. Be sure to put that as a separate accepted answer.